# Jersey REST web service with Hibernate causes NoSuchMethodError on JBoss EAP 6.4

Tags: java, rest, jersey, jboss-eap-6, hibernate-5.x

I'm trying to create a very simple Jersey REST webservice project with Hibernate 5. The problem is that when I debloy the WAR-file to JBoss EAP 6.4, I'm getting following exception: "The exception contained within MappableContainerException could not be mapped to a response, re-throwing to the HTTP container: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.hibernate.internal.CoreMessageLogger.debugf(Ljava/lang/String;I)V" When running the project as a Java Application on Eclipse, Hibernate works perfectly.

The project contains Item -domain class, ItemDAO -data access object, ItemManager which contains REST -method and hibernate.cfg.xml. I have googled and tried pretty much everything to solve exception, but nothing seems to help. if you have any ideas please help me.

Exception:

```
    15:18:18,944 SEVERE [com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponse] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1) The exception contained within MappableContainerException could not be mapped to a response, re-throwing to the HTTP container: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.hibernate.internal.CoreMessageLogger.debugf(Ljava/lang/String;I)V
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.configure(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:87) [hibernate-core-5.0.1.Final.jar:5.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:94) [hibernate-core-5.0.1.Final.jar:5.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:217) [hibernate-core-5.0.1.Final.jar:5.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:189) [hibernate-core-5.0.1.Final.jar:5.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.buildJdbcConnectionAccess(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:145) [hibernate-core-5.0.1.Final.jar:5.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:66) [hibernate-core-5.0.1.Final.jar:5.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:35) [hibernate-core-5.0.1.Final.jar:5.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.initiateService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:88) [hibernate-core-5.0.1.Final.jar:5.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:234) [hibernate-core-5.0.1.Final.jar:5.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:208) [hibernate-core-5.0.1.Final.jar:5.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:189) [hibernate-core-5.0.1.Final.jar:5.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.configure(JdbcServicesImpl.java:51) [hibernate-core-5.0.1.Final.jar:5.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:94) [hibernate-core-5.0.1.Final.jar:5.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:217) [hibernate-core-5.0.1.Final.jar:5.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:189) [hibernate-core-5.0.1.Final.jar:5.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.handleTypes(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:352) [hibernate-core-5.0.1.Final.jar:5.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:111) [hibernate-core-5.0.1.Final.jar:5.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.build(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:83) [hibernate-core-5.0.1.Final.jar:5.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataBuilderImpl.build(MetadataBuilderImpl.java:418) [hibernate-core-5.0.1.Final.jar:5.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataBuilderImpl.build(MetadataBuilderImpl.java:87) [hibernate-core-5.0.1.Final.jar:5.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:692) [hibernate-core-5.0.1.Final.jar:5.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:724) [hibernate-core-5.0.1.Final.jar:5.0.1.Final]
    at org.item.dao.ItemDAO.getItembyId(ItemDAO.java:17) [classes:]
    at org.item.manager.ItemManager.getItem(ItemManager.java:22) [classes:]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.8.0_51]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) [rt.jar:1.8.0_51]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) [rt.jar:1.8.0_51]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497) [rt.jar:1.8.0_51]
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.JavaMethodInvokerFactory$1.invoke(JavaMethodInvokerFactory.java:60) [jersey-bundle-1.19.jar:1.19]
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider$ResponseOutInvoker._dispatch(AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider.java:205) [jersey-bundle-1.19.jar:1.19]
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.dispatch(ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.java:75) [jersey-bundle-1.19.jar:1.19]
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.HttpMethodRule.accept(HttpMethodRule.java:302) [jersey-bundle-1.19.jar:1.19]
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147) [jersey-bundle-1.19.jar:1.19]
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.ResourceClassRule.accept(ResourceClassRule.java:108) [jersey-bundle-1.19.jar:1.19]
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147) [jersey-bundle-1.19.jar:1.19]
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RootResourceClassesRule.accept(RootResourceClassesRule.java:84) [jersey-bundle-1.19.jar:1.19]
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1542) [jersey-bundle-1.19.jar:1.19]
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1473) [jersey-bundle-1.19.jar:1.19]
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1419) [jersey-bundle-1.19.jar:1.19]
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1409) [jersey-bundle-1.19.jar:1.19]
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:409) [jersey-bundle-1.19.jar:1.19]
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:558) [jersey-bundle-1.19.jar:1.19]
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:733) [jersey-bundle-1.19.jar:1.19]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847) [jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec-1.0.2.Final-redhat-2.jar:1.0.2.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:295) [jbossweb-7.5.7.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.7.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214) [jbossweb-7.5.7.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.7.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:231) [jbossweb-7.5.7.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.7.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:149) [jbossweb-7.5.7.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.7.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityContextAssociationValve.java:169) [jboss-as-web-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:150) [jbossweb-7.5.7.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.7.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:97) [jbossweb-7.5.7.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.7.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:102) [jbossweb-7.5.7.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.7.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:344) [jbossweb-7.5.7.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.7.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:854) [jbossweb-7.5.7.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.7.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:653) [jbossweb-7.5.7.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.7.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:926) [jbossweb-7.5.7.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.7.Final-redhat-1]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.8.0_51]

15:18:18,949 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/Item_dev-0.0.1].[Jersey REST Service]] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1) JBWEB000236: Servlet.service() for servlet Jersey REST Service threw exception: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.hibernate.internal.CoreMessageLogger.debugf(Ljava/lang/String;I)V
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.configure(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:87) [hibernate-core-5.0.1.Final.jar:5.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:94) [hibernate-core-5.0.1.Final.jar:5.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:217) [hibernate-core-5.0.1.Final.jar:5.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:189) [hibernate-core-5.0.1.Final.jar:5.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.buildJdbcConnectionAccess(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:145) [hibernate-core-5.0.1.Final.jar:5.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:66) [hibernate-core-5.0.1.Final.jar:5.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:35) [hibernate-core-5.0.1.Final.jar:5.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.initiateService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:88) [hibernate-core-5.0.1.Final.jar:5.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:234) [hibernate-core-5.0.1.Final.jar:5.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:208) [hibernate-core-5.0.1.Final.jar:5.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:189) [hibernate-core-5.0.1.Final.jar:5.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.configure(JdbcServicesImpl.java:51) [hibernate-core-5.0.1.Final.jar:5.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:94) [hibernate-core-5.0.1.Final.jar:5.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:217) [hibernate-core-5.0.1.Final.jar:5.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:189) [hibernate-core-5.0.1.Final.jar:5.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.handleTypes(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:352) [hibernate-core-5.0.1.Final.jar:5.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:111) [hibernate-core-5.0.1.Final.jar:5.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.build(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:83) [hibernate-core-5.0.1.Final.jar:5.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataBuilderImpl.build(MetadataBuilderImpl.java:418) [hibernate-core-5.0.1.Final.jar:5.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataBuilderImpl.build(MetadataBuilderImpl.java:87) [hibernate-core-5.0.1.Final.jar:5.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:692) [hibernate-core-5.0.1.Final.jar:5.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:724) [hibernate-core-5.0.1.Final.jar:5.0.1.Final]
    at org.item.dao.ItemDAO.getItembyId(ItemDAO.java:17) [classes:]
    at org.item.manager.ItemManager.getItem(ItemManager.java:22) [classes:]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.8.0_51]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) [rt.jar:1.8.0_51]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) [rt.jar:1.8.0_51]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497) [rt.jar:1.8.0_51]
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.JavaMethodInvokerFactory$1.invoke(JavaMethodInvokerFactory.java:60) [jersey-bundle-1.19.jar:1.19]
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider$ResponseOutInvoker._dispatch(AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider.java:205) [jersey-bundle-1.19.jar:1.19]
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.dispatch(ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.java:75) [jersey-bundle-1.19.jar:1.19]
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.HttpMethodRule.accept(HttpMethodRule.java:302) [jersey-bundle-1.19.jar:1.19]
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147) [jersey-bundle-1.19.jar:1.19]
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.ResourceClassRule.accept(ResourceClassRule.java:108) [jersey-bundle-1.19.jar:1.19]
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147) [jersey-bundle-1.19.jar:1.19]
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RootResourceClassesRule.accept(RootResourceClassesRule.java:84) [jersey-bundle-1.19.jar:1.19]
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1542) [jersey-bundle-1.19.jar:1.19]
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1473) [jersey-bundle-1.19.jar:1.19]
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1419) [jersey-bundle-1.19.jar:1.19]
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1409) [jersey-bundle-1.19.jar:1.19]
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:409) [jersey-bundle-1.19.jar:1.19]
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:558) [jersey-bundle-1.19.jar:1.19]
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:733) [jersey-bundle-1.19.jar:1.19]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847) [jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec-1.0.2.Final-redhat-2.jar:1.0.2.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:295) [jbossweb-7.5.7.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.7.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214) [jbossweb-7.5.7.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.7.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:231) [jbossweb-7.5.7.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.7.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:149) [jbossweb-7.5.7.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.7.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityContextAssociationValve.java:169) [jboss-as-web-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:150) [jbossweb-7.5.7.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.7.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:97) [jbossweb-7.5.7.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.7.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:102) [jbossweb-7.5.7.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.7.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:344) [jbossweb-7.5.7.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.7.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:854) [jbossweb-7.5.7.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.7.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:653) [jbossweb-7.5.7.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.7.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:926) [jbossweb-7.5.7.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.7.Final-redhat-1]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.8.0_51]
```

Domain class:

```
package org.item.domain;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@Entity
@Table(name = "ITEM")
@XmlRootElement(name = "Item")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Item {

    @Id
    @XmlElement(name = "ItemId", required = true)
    private String itemId;

    @Column
    @XmlElement(name = "ItemName", required = false)
    private String itemName;

    public String getItemId() {
        return itemId;
    }

    public void setItemId(String itemId) {
        this.itemId = itemId;
    }

    public String getItemName() {
        return itemName;
    }

    public void setItemName(String itemName) {
        this.itemName = itemName;
    }

}
```

DAO-class:

```
package org.item.dao;

import org.hibernate.HibernateException;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.Transaction;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;
import org.item.domain.Item;

public class ItemDAO {

    Session session;

    public Item getItembyId(String itemId) {

        try {

            session = new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory()
                    .getCurrentSession();

        } catch (HibernateException e) {

            System.out.println("Exception thrown");
            e.printStackTrace();

        }

        Transaction transaction = session.beginTransaction();

        transaction.begin();

        Item item = (Item) session.get(Item.class, itemId);

        transaction.commit();

        return item;

    }

}
```

Manager

```
package org.item.manager;

import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;

import org.item.dao.ItemDAO;
import org.item.domain.Item;

@Path("{resources}")
public class ItemManager {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ItemManager im = new ItemManager();
        im.getItem();

    }

    @Path("{id}")
    @GET
    @Produces({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON })
    public Response getItem() {

        ItemDAO itemDAO = new ItemDAO();

        Item item = itemDAO.getItembyId("I001");

        return Response.ok(item).build();
    }

}
```

hibernate.cfg.xml

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration">

<hibernate-configuration>

    <session-factory>
        <property name="connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
        <property name="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/ITEM</property>
        <property name="connection.username">itemtest</property>
        <property name="connection.password">itempass</property>

        <property name="connection.pool_size">1</property>
        <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
        <property name="current_session_context_class">thread</property>
        <property name="cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.NoCacheProvider</property>
        <property name="show_sql">true</property>
        <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>

        <mapping class="org.item.domain.Item" />

    </session-factory>

</hibernate-configuration>
```

POM.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>org.Item</groupId>
    <artifactId>Item_dev</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <build>
        <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4</version>
                <configuration>
                    <warSourceDirectory>WebContent</warSourceDirectory>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencies>

        <!-- JAXB -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.12</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- REST -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-bundle</artifactId>
            <version>1.19</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-json</artifactId>
            <version>1.19</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- HIBERNATE -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.12</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.javassist</groupId>
            <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
            <version>3.18.2-GA</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- MYSQL Driver -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.36</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

</project>
```

Comment: Well EAP uses Hibernate 4 and it doesn't use Jersey. JBoss EAP is a Java EE container which already provides the JPA and JAX-RS implementations for you.

Comment: Thank you James! I obviously need to get back to the book for the basics. This solved my problem.